# Adaptive Wiener Filter Coefficients Calculation

Tags: linear-prediction

I want to extrapolate a signal **X** of length 11, using the weiner filter coefficients ***W*** of length 7. The procedure I am using is as follows:

1. Compute the autocorrelation matrix upto lag 8 .
2. Using Levinson recursion, invert the autocorrelation matrix ***A***.
3. Multiply the matrix of cross-correlations with the ***inv(A)*** to get ***W***
4. Obtain **Extrapolated Sample=Sum(W.*Signal)**

My questions is that, if now I have a new signal **Y** of length **15** as:
**Y**=[**X** (4 new samples)]

So the Signal **Y** has first 11 samples of **X** and 4 new samples.

Now I want to compute weiner coefficients of this signal, given that I have already computed those for the signal **X**, can you recommend any possible approach to 'update' the filter co-efficients ***W*** given the 4 new samples, without having to do the whole weiner filter computation again thus saving some computational time?

**Edit 1:**

I have written the code for LMS Algorithm to iteratively 'adapt', when a new sample arrives, the filter co-efficients which were initially derived by Weiner Prediction.

The result is not same as the Weiner coefficients derived on the whole input.

The code is:

`` `FilterOrder=7; ``

```
Window=7;

Filter=zeros(1,FilterOrder);

x = -20*%pi:0.1:20*%pi; 

m=length(x);

StepSize=2.3e-4/1000000;

data=[cos(2*x(1:floor(m/2))) cos(3.3*x(floor(m/2)+1:m))];

Filter=WeinerCtrace(data(1:Window+1),FilterOrder);   // Initial Co-efficients

for i=1:50

Input=data(1+i:Window+i);               // Sliding Window of Filter Input

DesiredOutput=data(Window+1+i);         // New sample value 

ActualOutput=Input(Window:-1:1)*Filter';

Error=DesiredOutput-ActualOutput;

while(1)

    NewFilter=Filter+StepSize*Error*Input;     // Gradient Descent 


    if(sum((NewFilter-Filter).^2)<1e-20)

        break;

    end

    Filter=NewFilter;

end

Filter=NewFilter;

end
WCoefficients=WeinerCtrace(data(1:Window+i+1),FilterOrder)
```

Now, according to my opinion the values of **WCoefficients** and **Filter** should match as the **WCoefficients** are computed by applying Weiner Prediction on all the arrived data, while **Filter** is computed iteratively on introduction of every new sample.

**Edit 2:**
I have also implemented the RLS algorithm code given below, but the output of RLS still does not match the output of Weiner Prediction Coefficients for the same window:

```
FilterOrder=11;
Window=11;
t=0:1:1000;
f=linspace(.5,5,length(t));
fs=100;
data=cos((%pi/fs)*(f.*t));
[Filter,P]=WeinerCtrace(data(1:Window+1),FilterOrder);
w=1;
plot(data,'-r');
for i=1:500
    Input=data(Window+i:-1:1+i)';           // Sliding Window of Filter Input
    DesiredOutput=data(Window+1+i);         // New sample value 
    ActualOutput=Input'*Filter;
    Error=DesiredOutput-ActualOutput;
    K=(P*Input)/(w+(Input'*P*Input));
    P=(P-(K*Input'*P))/w;
    Filter=Filter+(K*Error);
end
inp=data(i+1:Window+i+1);
WC=WeinerCtrace(inp,FilterOrder)
inp=data(i+1:Window+i);
for j=1:100
   NextValue=inp(11+j-1:-1:j)*WC;
   inp=[inp NextValue];
   plot(Window+1+i+j,NextValue,'r+')
end
inp=data(Window+i:-1:1+i);
for j=1:100
   NextValue=inp(1:Window)*Filter;
   inp=[NextValue inp];
   plot(Window+1+i+j,NextValue,'b*')
end
```

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong in the code or in anything else ?
Any suggestions/idea is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of the [LMS algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter)? Does it help?

Comment: Thanks Peter. The LMS algorithm does indeed fit in my scenario. I do not know whether it will be faster than Weiner Filter computation as we have to do Gradient Descent in LMS, can you provide your opinion about it?

Comment: [Recursive Least Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares) also seems helpful for this scenario doesn't it ?

Comment: The Wiener filter is, by definition a) not adaptive and b) not FIR / AR. You seem to want an adaptive FIR filter.  There are many variants of this: LMS, NLMS, RLS (as you say), or the Kalman filter. Choose your poison! :-)  ALL of them are less computationally intensive that the Wiener filter.

Comment: @PeterK. Should probably post your last comment as an answer.

Comment: @Phonon Done! And some extra characters to make it take a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wiener filter is, by definition

a) not adaptive and

b) not FIR / AR.

You seem to want an adaptive FIR filter.

There are many variants of this: [LMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter), [NLMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter#Normalised_least_mean_squares_filter_.28NLMS.29), [RLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares) (as you say), or the [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). Choose your poison! :-)

ALL of them are (generally) less computationally intensive that the Wiener filter.

Comment: can you please have a look at the updated question? Thanks.

Comment: Ask another question! This is a little too different from your first cut.